# Where can I find prebuilt Subversion binaries for SGI IRIX?

Tags: svn, version-control, sgi, irix

We have a few SGI Onyx 350 and Orgin 350 systems running IRIX 6.5.x that we would like to install Subversion on.  One of them will likely be used as a simple repository server running svnserve.  The others will only need client installs.

The Subversion webpage has links to unofficial binaries for many *NIX systems, including HP-UX, Solaris, AIX, the BSDs and Linux distros.  Unfortunately, there aren't any for IRIX.  A Google search also comes up empty.

So, is there someplace on the web that publishes IRIX binaries for Subversion?

If not, does anyone have experience compiling SVN from source on such systems?  How hard is it to track down all of the dependencies?  Are there any caveats we should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a machine like yours, the source code build is probably the way to go(it's one of the advantages of having source).  The dependencies aren't that bad.  The dependencies are [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org) (and the apr-utils), [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/) (optional), and [BerkelyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/berkeley-db/index.html)(optional also).
Get the Apache and neon, and berkelyDB stuff first.
then just ./configure --prefix=;make;make install

Answer (score 1):

The Nekoware repository has a binary of Subversion 1.5.5.

http://www.mechanics.citg.tudelft.nl/~everdij/nekoware/index.php?path=current/

Answer (score 0):

The guy that maintains [This website](http://www.futuretech.blinkenlights.nl/sgi.html) sells secondhand SGI gear.  He sells them with CD's of contributed software.  Maybe he can do something for you.

Also, [The SGI forum on nekochan.net](http://www.nekochan.net/weblog/archives/irix-software/) has postings of contributed software.  You may be able to ask for something there.

Subversion is fairly pernickety about its dependencies (as you have probably already worked out).  [This link](http://www.peregrinehw.com/downloads/subversion/INSTALL-rh7.3-last) gives some of the dependencies for installing on Redhat 7.3, which dates back to the early 2000's (I don't know what minor release of Irix you're using).  You may find it to be a reasonable guide to the dependencies.